# Entity Framework using a pure POCO model

Tags: entity-framework, model, poco

Is it possible in Entity Framework using Code First to create a domain model of pure POCOs that are totally ignorant of the Entity Framework?, i.e. don't decorate any classes or properties with any attributes and annotations related to the EF, and don't use virtual keyword to be able to support lazy loading.

Can I achieve this? or do I have to make two models one for persistence model and one for domain model to achieve this.

Comment: You don't need attributes. You can use the [fluent api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591617(v=vs.113).aspx) to separate your concerns. You can achieve lazy loading in code without virtual. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx).

Comment: You are correct, Fluent API can achieve the job. But for lazy loading I didn't find any way to do lazy loading without virtual keyword in the link you mentioned.

Comment: 2nd link: "Even with lazy loading disabled it is still possible to lazily load related entities, but it must be done with an explicit call. To do so you use the Load method on the related entity’s entry."